# Upload image and insert markdown code (with url) to textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I upload an image without page refresh; just using `input type="file"` to server. I'm using PHP to upload the file. I also need to insert markdown code with a URL to the image, like this: `![Image.](/url/to/image.png)` to end of a `textarea`.

How can I do this? Maybe using JS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

You can have basic php image upload script at server side..